# Print gridlines in OpenXML Spreadsheet

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010, openxml, openxml-sdk

My current Task includes the programmatically generation of .xslx files with various functions like AutoFilter or displaying Grid lines on printing with Excel 2010.

However i fail to properly add the PrintOptions for Gridlines.
According to the [MSDN Dokumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.printoptions(v=office.14).aspx), PrintOptions is a leaf of the Worksheet, yet the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.WorkSheet Namespace does not include a function to append the PrintOptions, and using the .Append() or .AppendChild() will result in a corrupted Spreadsheet.

```
Dim po = New PrintOptions With {.GridLines = True}  
sheetPart.Worksheet.Append(po)
```

I also used the OpenXML Productivity Tool to compare my own created Spreadsheet vs the one from Excel 2010 and i noticed that the only difference between my Spreadsheet and Excels is that mine have a xml-namespace while the Excel ones does not.

May someone illuminate me what the correct way for inserting the PrintOptions into a Spreadsheet is? I spend days on those two lines now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a order in which the elements have to be inserted.

**If you have a PageSetup element in your Worksheet, this has to be appended AFTER the PrintOptions, otherwise you will get a corrupted Spreadsheet in Office 2010.**

This is the correct way to insert if you want a spreadsheet in Landscape, FitToWidth and Gridlines :

```
Dim po = New PrintOptions With {.GridLines = True}
sheetPart.Worksheet.Append(po)

Dim ps = New PageSetup With {.Orientation = OrientationValues.Landscape} 
Dim sp As New SheetProperties
sp.PageSetupProperties = New PageSetupProperties With {.FitToPage = True}
sheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties = sp
ps.FitToWidth = CUInt(1)
ps.FitToHeight = CUInt(0)
sheetPart.Worksheet.Append(ps)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Vincent Tan's *SpreadsheetOpenXmlFromScratch*:

```
Dim po As New PrintOptions()
po.HorizontalCentered = True
po.VerticalCentered = True
' print the row (1,2,3,...) and column (A,B,C,...) headings
po.Headings = True
' print the grid lines
**po.GridLines = True
' By default, GridLinesSet is true.
' Only when both GridLines and GridLinesSet are true, then grid lines are printed.**
' I don't know why there's an additional flip switch...
po.GridLinesSet = True
ws.Append(po)
```

Your code doesn't show you handling GridLinesSet = true

Comment: Sadly adding "GridLinesSet = True" does not help, the Worksheet still becomes corrupted.